# Ya no puedo ingresar a mi pagina desde otro dispositivo

Tags: servidor, xampp, localhost

Tuve que reinstalar mi Xampp y Mysql por causa de errores, si bien estos se solucionaron, ahora me ocurre otro error: cuando intento ingresar a mi localhost desde otro dispositivo, me sale ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, es el mismo mensaje que suele aparecer cuando mi pc (el que hace de servidor) está apagada, pero ahora aparece aun estando encendida.

Comment: Apache está en ejecución? Si intentas con la `ip` del equipo?

Comment: tu maquina y el otro dispositivos deben estar en la misma red, si lo anterior se cumple, en tu otro dispositivo coloca la ip de tu pc que tiene levantado el servicio

Comment: @Richard siempre he usado la ip de la pc servidor para ingresar desde otro dispositivo, y sí estan conectados en red, pero ahora no resulta.

Comment: El cliente está dando timeout porque espera a que alguien le responda y nadie le responde. Si haces `telnet ip_delequipo puerto_de_mysql` qué pasa?

Comment: @Alfabravo perdone, no le entiendo

Comment: @Alfabravo te está indicando un comando de consola para tratar de **comunicarte con el servidor via telnet** es otro protocolo de comunicación

Comment: @quevedo pero ese comando no se si lo escribió bien o mal porque no tiene sentido

Comment: cuando lees la propiedades de la conexión de tu equipo encuentras ip_delequipo, **telnet** es el comando cuando configuraste MySql le asignaste un puerto. Ese es puerto_de_mysql. Debes usar una consola (terminal en linux, no recuerdo como se llama en windows) hace tiempo no uso win_x

Comment: @Alfabravo en donde ingreso ese comando que dices? porque voy al cmd y no me lo reconoce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta desinstalar XAMPP y vuelve a instalarlo pero con el cortafuegos apagado!

También, puedes probar WAMP, es muy similar a XAMPP.

Éxitos!